# Python Mocking of Boolean Function

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

So I have just begun working with the mock library to perform some unit testing. But ran across a problem that is certainly mysterious to me.

When I call the below code stream.open() always evaluates to True, as it seems to be returning the Mock object rather than the False value.

Test Code

```
@patch('module.lib.stream')
def test_error_raised(self, mock_stream):
    mock_stream.open.return_value = False
    self.assertRaises(IOError, get_query, 618)
```

Called Function

```
def get_query(id):
    id = str(id)
    fpath = os.path.join(
        path, '{0}.pdf'.format(id))
    stream = stream()
    if not stream.open(fpath):
        raise IOError("No file found")
    list = map(foo, stream.GetData())
    first_entry = list[0]
    target_entries = list[1:]
    return first_entry, target_entries
```

Is there a way to properly mock this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your function here, `stream` seems to be a class.

Since you create an instance of that class and then you call the `open` method on that instance, you need to do `mock_stream.return_value.open.return_value = False` in the test function.